# How to use pipeline in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to convert a P12 file to a PEM file. When I execute the command, the terminal asks me for three things:

P12 passphrase (I type it in, hit enter)
PEM passphrase (type it in, hit enter)
PEM passphrase confirm (type it in, hit enter)

I know I can execute a sudo command all in one shot by using the following:

```
echo sudopassword | sudo rm -rf /file.p12;
```

How can I add all three values in one shot?

Comment: ... just don't lose the file.txt from the end of that command.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for responding, but could you be more clear? Should I do something like `echo password | echo password | echo password | normal command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical unix tool for this job is [expect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html).

Here is a [short tutorial](http://code.seanodonnell.com/?id=21) that should get you going on scripting a series of passwords to be entered when the appropriate prompt is detected by the tool.